# JQuery Mobile check if select menu is disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

in JQuery Mobile how do I check if select menu (html select) is disabled or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you would do as for a regular select, this way:

```
$('#yourselect').is('[disabled]') //returns true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to check the disabled property

```
$('yourselect').prop('disabled') // <-- will return true or false
```